# How does Apache Curator DistributedQueue's lockPath work?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I have a bunch of independent pieces of work that I need processes to perform. These pieces of work can be performed in any order, and they last long enough that processes sometimes fail when work is being performed.

I need to coordinate the assignment of these pieces of work, and Curator's DistributedQueue seems like it is *almost* what I want. I don't need the ordering it provides, though, so I am curious what level of overhead I am paying for that assuming I decline to have a single consumer (ie each process just consumes from the queue).

My main concern is how the lockPath() function on the queue builder actually works. I need the functionality it provides, because it is possible for processes to fail and I need to not be dropping the jobs they were supposed to be doing. But what I don't want is for only one process to be able to do any work at a time. If I use lockPath(), will the queue block for other processes while a process is consuming a message?

Also, if the queue seems like an unreasonable approach, is there another tool available to achieve what I want, or would I have to roll my own? I want to stay within the Curator / ZK environment but am open to alternatives within that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: I'm the main author of Apache Curator)

The documentation needs to be improved. The lock is used to make the queue entry retry-able. i.e. the entry in the queue is not removed until the consumer finishes. The lock assures that only 1 process is acting on the entry. If you don't care about dropping queue entries on failure you don't need to use the lock. With or without the lock, though, each consumer that you run processes queue entries. So, if you want to have concurrent processing of the queue you'd run multiple consumers (in the same JVM or in separate JVMs - it doesn't matter).

Here's a workflow engine I wrote that uses the Curator queue to do distributed work. Feel free to use it as it is open source: http://nirmataoss.github.io/workflow/

Comment: Thanks boss :) I'll take a look at your thing, and this answers my question.